# How can I select and run a block of python code?

Tags: python, eclipse, ide, pydev

Are there any IDEs which let me select a block of code in a Python script and run the selected code?

I'm using Eclipse + PyDev and can't figure it out.
Does anyone know how to do this (run a selection in the script instead of running the whole script)in Eclipse?

Thanks

Comment: Just paste it into the command line interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this *can* be done, but why? If you really want to just experiment with a portion of code, a possible approach is:

```
def a():
    # wrap your experimental code

def b():
    # wrap your other experimental code

if __name__ = '__main__':
    a()
    b() # for next time
```

This approach delivers multiple advantages:

1. Clear logical blocks, easier to maintain
2. Module is importable and doesn't run any portion of the code unless you call certain functions
3. Once the development's mature, you don't have to tear down this "experimental" module and rewrite another - it's production ready

So instead of "select-and-run", just "comment/uncomment-and-run". I don't see how much harder that can be :)

Answer (score 0):

Some IDEs such as WingIDE have a python console window that you can copy/paste blocks of code,  you can even ctrl-drag drop into it.  I think SPE has similar.  I am not running Eclipse if there is a python console window that is your best bet.